# Getting Error in scale.default(temp, x, FALSE) : length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Tags: r, data-mining, outliers

I am trying to implement the LOF algorithm in R using the `DMwR` package. The dataset I am using is the [Wisconsin Breast Cancer dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Original%29) from UCI machine learning repository (for the last column I have converted 2 to 'benign' and 4 to 'malignant') and it looks something like this in the csv file that I am importing it from:

```
"Clump Thickness","Uniformity of Cell Size", "Uniformity of Cell Shape","Marginal Adhesion" ,"Single Epithelial Cell Size","Bare Nuclei" , "Bland Chromatin" ,"Normal Nucleoli" ,"Mitoses" , "Class"  
5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,benign
5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,benign
3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,benign
```

Then I use these set of commands

```
breastcancer <- read.csv("breastcancer.csv", sep = ",")
breastcancer2 <- breastcancer[,1:9]
outlierscores <- lofactor(breastcancer2, k=5)
```

However, it is giving me the error:

```
Error in scale.default(temp, x, FALSE) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

Could anyone please help me in identifying the problem?

Comment: Could you add a link to the dataset?

Comment: The `DMwR` package is *incredibly slow*. :-( Plus, it is not supposed to automagically scale the data for you, this distorts distances.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse So, is the error due to the scaling? How do you recommend I solve it?

Comment: Scaling shouldn't be a problem, unless you have vectors of different length or missing values. But in the end **I don't use `DMwR`, it's too slow**. I can't ultimately help you except suggesting to use a different tool.

Comment: What are some other alternatives that I might try?

Answer (score 0):

lofactor() cannot calculate factor type data, please make sure your data type is numeric